# Why do immutable classes provide mutators?

Tags: java, immutability, bigdecimal

Consider the following code:

```
    bdval = new BigDecimal(strval, new MathContext(attrib.getPrecision()));
    bdval.setScale(attrib.getScale(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

[PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/) quite correctly says:

> Useless operation on Immutable

So why do Immutable classes like `BigDecimal` export mutators for properties?

Answer (score 8):

`setScale()` doesn't mutate the BigDecimal it's called on. It returns a copy of the BigDecimal with the new scale value.

PMD reports an error because YOUR code is wrong: it ignores the result of the operation making the operation useless. Your code should be:

```
bdval = bdval.setScale(attrib.getScale(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: then I would say this is poorly designed api.It should be static method and it violates the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: If `setScale` was static the code would be a lot more verbose `BigDecimal.setScale(bdval, attrib.getScale(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP);` with no real benefit - the logic still lives within the BigDecimal class. And there is a good argument to be made that logic for manipulating BigDecimals belongs in the BigDecimal class.

Comment: Granted, the _naming_ could use improvement -- I might've used `withScale` instead of `setScale`.  But I think the placement of the method is just fine.